# Reffering to an ID in different XML file

Tags: android, xml

I Have my MapsActivity, that has a onCreateMethod() as

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
```

I called a dialog box that can overlay the current activity for a while as

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MapsActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

It refers to ***dialog.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Enter Destination Name"
            android:id="@+id/textView8" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want my program to refer from ***MapsActivity*** to ***R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment*** in ***dialog.xml***

I Tried using `R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment` but it didn't work.

So how do i do this? HELPPP

Answer (score 0):

Try not having your fragment written into the xml directly. Instead allocate a holder view for your fragment, and then use the Fragment Manager to add that Fragment into that space Programmatically.

Comment: what do you mean? I am not that good with android just average :P

Comment: I'm assuming that you have a fragment that wrap's Google's Autocomplete Places. I think you might get a better sense of how to set this up by checking out this stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089123/google-places-autocomplete-android-fragment

You can see that they are replacing a view with that of the Fragment they want to use using the FragmentManager (and Fragment Transaction).

Comment: nope thats not the problem what i want is that a layout different from the .java be referred. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
dialog.findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment)
```

You will get the instance in MapsActivity itself.
Your question was not that clear to me, so hope this answer helps.